# Flying in V formation with multiple planes

Tags: fuel, autopilot, pilot-technique, efficiency, traffic-pattern

Logistically choreographed using air-traffic controllers to pair like planes headed in the same direction or by scheduling flights together, how much fuel could be saved pairing planes to fly in a tight V formation throughout a fleet?

Maybe an autopilot could both keep a heading while maintaining an optimal position with in the formation; or in other words, Auto-formation.

Comment: Are you asking about airliners flying in groups to save airspace (in which case you should title the question "how much money would be saved by flying airliners in formation to save airspace?"). In that case would you allow formation to break and reform with other airliners? Or are you asking about [effect of formation flying on overall drag](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235201614_Drag_Reduction_from_Formation_Flight_Flying_Aircraft_in_Bird-Like_Formations_Could_Significantly_Increase_Range) ?

Comment: I think he has the flock of geese in mind.  A small jet like an RJ could fly in the upwash forward and above the leading edge of a 747 and probably reduce its thrust significantly to stay in position, but who would want to ride in the thing.

Comment: @JohnK if you are right, there are already highly related questions (if not dupe): [Why isn't the V flight formation being used for commercial purposes?](/q/15188/3394), [How do planes benefit from flying in formation?](/q/16821/3394), [How much can a plane benefit from another planes wake?](/q/67102/3394)

Comment: The US Air Force has experimented with it and it seems they've [built the option into their auto-pilot programs](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16831).